# Admob Ads on iOS 4.3 Error-GADObjectPrivate

Tags: ios, admob

I am getting the following error on a new app:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADObjectPrivate
>   changeState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed49a90'.

I have a couple ad networks-Chartboost and Admob. This seems like an Admob error, but it is causing the app to terminate on launch. I have removed the admob code and files, and I am still getting the error.

I don't know if this helps anyone:

> *** First throw call stack: (0x374ca2a3 0x34fca97f 0x374cde07 0x374cc531 0x37423f68 0x9e950 0xa0314 0x9deb0 0x6e147 0x36e53595
>   0x36e93d79 0x36e8faed 0x36ed11d1 0x6de0d 0x36e94ad9 0x36e94663
>   0x36e8c84b 0x36e34c41 0x36e346d5 0x36e34123 0x350c75a3 0x3749f683
>   0x3749eee9 0x3749dcb7 0x37410ebd 0x37410d49 0x36e8b485 0x36e88301
>   0x6db2d 0x6da90) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an
>   exception

Answer (score 2):

Which version of AdMob are you using? If you are using v6.2, you must use the -ObjC linker flag in the "Other Linker Flags" section of Build Settings. If you are using v6.1 or below, you have to use the -all_load linker flag.

Also, if you're using v6.2, you must be using XCode 4.5 and targeting iOS 6 (you can set your minimum deployment target to iOS 4.3 though).